# Difference between function name {function()} and component name <Component/> in react render function?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to draw a table in react using the following syntax:

```
return (
        <div>    
          <button className = 'retryButton' onClick = {restartGame}>Play again</button>
         {CreateBoard()}
         </div> 
  );
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. What is the difference between using `{CreateBoard()}` and `<CreateBoard/>` ?
2. When I use `<CreateBoard/>` I notice that the background does not get filled. It stays blank. But when I use  `{CreateBoard()}` in return then the background color gets changed as expected. Why is that?
3. I am trying to reset the board when the player restarts the game. But the background color does not disappear. Why is that? How do I reset the board completely ?

```
const CreateBoard = () => {    
        console.log("here");
        return (
            <table >
                <tbody> 
                    {
                        boardSlots.map(item => 
                            <tr>
                                {
                                    item.map(value => {
                                        return (
                                            <td id = {value} onClick = { () => {cellClicked(value)} } />
                                        )
                                    })
                                }
                            </tr>
                        )
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }


----------------------------------------------
When the cell in a table is clicked I run the following function:
const cellClicked = (value) => {
       // value is x and y table coordinates.
       document.getElementById(x+"-"+next).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
       let slots = filledSlots;
       slots[parseInt(x)].push(next);
       setFilledSlots(slots);

}
----------------------------------------------
When the player clicks retry button I trigger this function:
const restartGame = () => {
        
        setFilledSlots([[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The difference between `{CreateBoard()}` and `<CreateBoard/>` - while you are using `{CreateBoard()}` you simply calls a  function which returns some HTML,  the react-dom won't treat it as a component instead you will have a single component which includes the HTML returned by that function. `<CreateBoard/>` - this is the right way of composing a react component using children. Make sure to pass the props `boardSlots`.
2. There is a problem I can see in this code snippet

> const CreateBoard = () => {
> console.log("here");
> return (
>
>
> {    boardSlots.map(item =>

You are not passing the prop  `boardSlots` , try changing your component like this `const CreateBoard = ({boardSlots}) => {`

And it is not a good idea to change the DOm directly like this  `document.getElementById(x+"-"+next).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";`, instead use a state to set and  change the back ground color.

Also make sure `const cellClicked = (value) => {` this function is inside the `CreateBoard`   component.

Comment: Yes, dom part was my bad but this "You are not passing the prop boardSlots , try changing your component like this const CreateBoard = ({boardSlots}) => {  ". Why can you not use class / main function level variable ?